# How to set an image with a delay

Tags: android, timer, imageview, delay

I have an "Activity" with three images. When one image is clicked, all the images are to switch to another picture. Is there a way to make the switches such that there is a 2 second delay before the images actually change (i.e. a 2 second delay in every 'for loop' below)? I am trying to do this with a timer but it does not actually to the delay when I run my program:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
image1.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
do_switches();
}

private void do_switches() 
{
//loop through all images and change them
for(int j=1 ;j<=3; j++)
{           


 final int curr2=current;
 final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
 Timer t = new Timer(); 
 t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
       public void run() { 
        handler.post(new Runnable() { 
               public void run() { 

        switch(curr2){

        case 1:

            image1.setImageResource(ImageArray[1]);
                    break;

        case 2:

            image2.setImageResource(ImageArray[2]);
                             break;

        case 3:
            image3.setImageResource(ImageArray[3]);
                        break;

        }
            } 
        }); 
    } 
 }, 2000); 
}
```

}

I have also tried using just SystemClock.sleep(2000) instead of the timer but I that didnt work either.I also tried setting up a Thread with a try/catch with no luck or maybe I didn't implement it properly. Is there a way to put this delay on every iteration of my for loop? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not one of best option, but still you can try CountDownTimer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: I first store the sequence of images to change in an array then I use the countdown timer to actually change the images. But when I make my interval a small number (less than ~2000ms) it misses the last 1 or 2 slots of my array. Do you know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long timeInMillis). Make your runnable that changes the pictures and then call postDelayed() and pass in the runnable and 2000 for the time delay.

Edit: Ahh I see what you are trying to do. As far as I know you aren't going to be able to make a for loop pause for 2 seconds each time through. You can get the same effect though if you chain the postDelayed() calls. Just set up the next runnable and call postDelayed() on it inside the first one, and same for the third one from inside the second one. You will end up with the same functionality as a for loop that pauses for 2 seconds each iteration.

Comment: I just tried doing what you said but my for loop still moves on to the next iteration even though the two seconds has not yet elapsed. How can I make the current iteration of the for loop wait till the 2 seconds has passed before it continues?

Comment: In my case I will be calling thesame runnable several times though. How would I do this?